# Add fields to wordpress footer

Tags: wordpress, footer

I have a wordpress widget on my footer with contact details and the widget has editable fields:

- Title
- Email
- Phone
- Fax
- Address

How can I edit this widget to include additional fields? I am new to wordpress and I am unsure if this is possible. In the help documentation for the widget it says the following:

#### How do I add additional fields to the contact widget?

Adding additional fields to the contact widget is as simple as adding a WordPress filter.

Here is an example:

add_filter( 'wpcw_widget_contact_custom_fields', function( $fields, $instance ) {

  $fields['cellphone'] = [
    'order'       => 2,
    'label'       => __( 'Cellphone:', 'YOURTEXTDOMAIN' ),
    'type'        => 'text',
    'description' => __( 'A cellphone number that website vistors can call if they have questions.', 'YOURTEXTDOMAIN' ),
  ];

  return $fields;

}, 10, 2 );

However I am unsure as to where I would have to add this information

Answer (score 0):

Widgets were originally designed to provide a simple and easy-to-use way of giving design and structure control of the WordPress Theme to the user, which is now available on properly "digitized" WordPress Themes to include the header, footer, and elsewhere in the WordPress design and structure. Widgets require no code experience or expertise. They can be added, removed, and rearranged on the Theme Customizer or Appearance > Widgets in the WordPress Administration Screens.

[more details](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets)

2> visit blog i [follow](http://wpfab.com/how-to-customize-a-specific-wordpress-widget/)

Answer (score 0):

if the widget don't have optionnal fields options altering it with new code can be the wrong approach. If the widget is updated you will loose your update.

The right way is to create a new widget with all the functions you need, maybe you can fork the existing widget and implementing your field.

Or you can just edit the `footer.php`and including the widget logic in it.

Docs :

- [Widget api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)
- [Template development in wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)